# grep whole non-alphanumeric strings and non-numbers

Tags: regex, bash, unix, grep

if I have:

```
abc a1b2c3 123
```

How can I grep whole strings that are not an alphanumeric character or a number so that I get

```
abc
```

I thought I could use the `-F` flag in conjunction with `[^0-9]` i.e.

```
grep -F '[^0-9]' filename
```

and return whole strings that do not contain numbers - but this does not return anything.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you just want to match alpha words, those without any numeric part, say:

```
grep -o "\b[[:alpha:]]*\b"
```

- `\b` matches the empty string at the edge of a word
- `[[:alpha:]]` matches alpha characters. That is, A-Za-z plus your local ones.

With your example:

```
$ echo "abc a1b2c3 123" | grep -o "\b[[:alpha:]]*\b"
abc
```

Comment: I was trying the command ..but it is not finding all the combinations in the string .`echo "abc a1b2c3 123 xyz aqw2" | grep -o "\b[[:alpha:]]*\b"` and the output was 
`abc`  . Any idea @fedorqui

Comment: @MathewsJose it really depends on what `grep` you are using, since it may not understand `[[:alpha:]]`. In my cygwin it properly returns `abc` and `xyz`.

Answer (score 1):

Like this :

```
grep -wo '[^0-9]*' file
```

- `-w` - Matches against whole words
- `-o` - Print only the matched pattern

Answer (score 1):

You can use `--word-regexp` (`-w`) to match only the words that does not contain any digit:

```
$ grep -wo '[^[:digit:]]\+' <<<'abc a1b2c3 123'   
abc
```

`-o` will print only the matched portion.

Comment: Thanks so much - is there an advantage of using `[[:digit:]]` over `[0-9]`?

Comment: @brucezepplin The character class `[:digit:]` will expand to values based on your locale but in this case `[0-9]` would work just fine..